# Is there an easy way to put my entire installation of Intellij on a USB stick?

Tags: intellij-idea, usb, portable-applications

I'm considering switching from Eclipse to Intellij.  One thing I like about Eclipse is that the whole installation is just a folder, and I can put that on a USB stick and copy it to another computer if I want.  All of my plugins, settings, and everything else come with me and all I have to do is simply copy a folder.

Is there any way I could do this with Intellij?

Comment: Yeah, there's just a special procedure you'd have to take up, I suspect. Dunno how this would behave with licenses (no worries if you use the community edition, though).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, just copy the installation directory to the flash drive, then edit `IDEA_HOME\bin\idea.properties` file, change the values of `idea.config.path` and `idea.plugins.path` to the relative location, like: `../config` and `../user-plugins` (locations are relative to IDEA bin directory).

Now copy your original settings and third-party plug-ins (if any):

- `${user.home}/.IntelliJIdea10/config` => `usb:/IDEA_HOME/config`
- `${user.home}/.IntelliJIdea10/config/plugins` => `usb:/IDEA_HOME/user-plugins`

Note that it's **not** recommended to change `idea.system.path` variable, so that it remains on the fast local drive, otherwise it could affect IDEA performance and occupy a lot of USB drive space.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The only problem is now it keeps my customizations, but not my "Activation" information. Everytime I should enter my License information to in order to use it. Is there a way to avoid this, too?

Comment: @Hooman if the license `.key` file is present in the [config folder](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23379538), it should not ask for the license again.

Comment: that's odd because I have `idea14.key` in my moved config folder but it seems it doesn't recognize it at the startup. Anyway I don't mind typing it once a day! Thanks for your answer.

Comment: you have to remove # from begging of line. also i think it is better you change log path and plugins path. but remember remove # from begging of line.

Answer (score 13):

One thing you could also do is to use the ${idea.home} path variable. I described in an article how you can create a portable version of IntelliJ IDEA including a version of the JDK.

https://leolabs.org/blog/making-intellij-portable/

I hope it can help you, as this is my first article in English ;)

Regards
leolabs

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that you should post the useful points of an answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted as ["Not an Answer"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Comment: leolabs is marked by google chrome _and_ my antivirus as being unsafe and has been blocked. -1

Comment: that's weird. Could you give more information? I don't like my blog being marked as unsafe ;)

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the answer of CrazyCoder:

To copy the "system" folder of IntelliJ / PHPStorm to the usb memory stick is required if you want that IntelliJ / PHPStorm behave like a portable app.

To get the desired folders install IntelliJ / PHPStorm to your HDD and run it at least one time.

On Windows 7 the path is (copy the folders to your usb memory stick):

- %USERNAME%\.WebIde10\config\ => usb:/IDEA_HOME/config
- %USERNAME%\.WebIde10\system\ => usb:/IDEA_HOME/user-plugins

Note that user-plugins is not created at first start of IntelliJ / PHPStorm, so create it on your usb memory stick.

Edit the idea.properties as CrazyCoder told you and change all 3 values:

- idea.config.path
- idea.plugins.path
- idea.system.path

Answer (score 3):

open `c:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\bin\idea.properties`

- change `# idea.config.path=${user.home}/.IntelliJIdea/config` to `idea.config.path=../PortableSetting/config`
- change `# idea.system.path=${user.home}/.IntelliJIdea/system` to `idea.system.path=../PortableSetting/system`
- change `# idea.plugins.path=${idea.config.path}/plugins` to `idea.plugins.path=../PortableSetting/config/plugins`
- change `# idea.log.path=${idea.system.path}/log` to `idea.log.path=../PortableSetting/system/log`

make `PortableSetting` folder in `c:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\`

copy content of `C:\Documents and Settings\User\.IntelliJIdea14\` to `c:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3\PortableSetting\`

copy `c:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3` to USB and enjoy!

I wrote this answer for windows XP default directory.

for more information about default directory look at [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs).

*I read other people answers and made an step by step answer.*

Comment: For Windows 10, the app data is here: 'C:\Users\{your user name}\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3' and also here: 'C:\Users\{your user name}\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3'

Answer (score 0):

You can use portableapps platform for portable intellij. Details description is [here](https://zahidhasan.github.io/2020/12/24/make-portable-intellij-jdk-for-usb-pendrive.html).