# Portable install of WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm, portable-applications

Is there a simple way to get a portable (USB stick) installation of WebStorm?

I've found a few posts around the 'Net about how to do it for PHPStorm (rename the .exe file to .zip, unpack and edit a particular setup file), but that doesn't seem to be working for me with WebStorm - when I go to unpack the .zip file, I get a pop-up asking me to insert the last disk of a multi-volume set...

Comment: Please look more information in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809214/is-there-an-easy-way-to-put-my-entire-installation-of-intellij-on-a-usb-stick/4809629#4809629

Answer (score 0):

You may use this [portable version](https://github.com/tvollstaedt/WebStormPortable) of WebStorm. This is an unofficial portable app and it is pakaged in the portableapps.com format.

This version supports migrating your existing WebStrom install's appdata to the new portable version. But you need to copy the .WebIde data folder to the Root/Data folder in the portable app directory.