# Make IntelliJ IDEA 15 portable

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-15

There are a lot of Tutorials on how to make IntelliJ IDEA 14 portable, but 14 is outdated now

The Version 15 does somehow ignore the idea.properties file in /bin/, and setting %USERPROFILE% to %cd%..\portable does also not work

So how to I make this installation portable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4809629/104891

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

Adding

```
-Duser.home=../../../portable/
```

To the idea(64).exe.vmoptions makes it use the folder portable next to the bin folder