# Create a portable version of intellij 15

Tags: java, intellij-idea, portable-applications

I am trying to create a portable version of Intellij, so that I can use it on a computer where I have restricted permissions. 
I have tried out the following tutorials:

http://leolabs.org/blog/making-intellij-portable/
where the system files with the {idea.home} parameters are changed in the idea.properties file.

and the SO question [Make IntelliJ IDEA 15 portable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35536638/make-intellij-idea-15-portable)
where the user profile is changed int the idea.exe.vmoptions to -Duser.home=../../../portable/

I am receiving a java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find installation home path. Please make sure bin/ide.properties is present in the installation directory.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read this article: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: but do you know that intelliJ doesn't need admin permissions to install? You just can install it in your user's folder.

Comment: No I hat no Idea, I received  a UAC Request, and exited the installer assuming it would fail. Thank you very much.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4809629/104891