# Is it possible to have the file paths in PyCharm's idea.properties file to point to variable drive locations?

Tags: pycharm

I've looked high and low for a solution for this but I've failed to find anything that does what I want...

Below is my idea.properties file for PyCharm, is there any way to have these variables (The 'idea.config.path=') all point to the same file path but variably change the drive letter? For example, use "D:/Pycharm/PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2.2/properties - settings/idea.properties" instead of "J:/Pycharm/PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2.2/properties - settings/idea.properties"

Or, alternatively, direct it to the folders relative to the location of the idea.properties file itself? For example, instead of "J:/Pycharm/PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2.2/bin", use "../bin" which would direct it to enter the parent directory of 'properties - settings' and enter the 'bin' folder, using the the 'properties - settings' folder as a relative path.

I understand that this may be unnecessary or impossible, just let me know if I'm asking for too much here.

```
# custom PyCharm properties

IDEA_PROPERTIES="J:/Pycharm/PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2.2/properties - settings/idea.properties"

idea.config.path="J:/Pycharm/PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2.2/properties - settings/config"
idea.system.path="J:/Pycharm/PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2.2/properties - settings/properties - settings"
idea.plugins.path="J:/Pycharm/PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2.2/properties - settings/plugins"
idea.log.path="J:/Pycharm/PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2.2/properties - settings/logs"
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Do you intend to install PyCharm on a removable drive that can change drive letter?

Comment: @bad_coder , that is the basic idea I had in mind. I'm aware of portable pycharm, which may be a simpler solution. However, I just wanted to know if it were possible to continue with my first choice.

Comment: If the links in [this thread](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000390450-PyCharm-Professional-Portable) don't work for you then it won't be possible. I also think this thread is a duplicate of [Is there an easy way to put my entire installation of Intellij on a USB stick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809214)