# Make PyCharm portable

Tags: python, pycharm

Sorry for my bad English. I want to make the PyCharm Community version portable with Interpreter settings. That means for example, i have python with all my libs, some external libs, my Projects and the IDE in one Folder and i want to put this folder everywhere, for example on an usb stick and from there to an linux pc and run my projects from there.

when i put the folder to an usb stick the interpreter path and paths to my libs must be changed manually. Is there an opion to do it automatically or with a batch-file? The paths have to be specified somewhere in the PyCharm-folder, but i dont know where i can find them?

Comment: PyCharm is an editor (or better an IDE), not an environment to run programs. I do not think you can do PyCharm "portable", but you can do your program portable (use virtual environment with correct flags to store all data within your project folder), but this is a different question

Comment: I would say you should not make the environment portable as well. Use `requirements.txt`, or `Poetry`, or `Pipenv` to describe the environment setup and recreate it on each new machine. Store your project under `git` and upload it e.g. to Github.

Comment: As @PavelKarateev says,  you should only save your source code, along with e.g. requirements.txt. In PyCharm, you can import the project using open, and use requirements.txt to recreate the virtual environment.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/managing-dependencies.html#create-requirements

Answer (score 0):

The paths are a file called idea.properties located in the same folder as the pycharm64.exe (or pycharm.exe) file.

There is an old StackOverflow ticket about this: [Is there an easy way to put my entire installation of Intellij on a USB stick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809214/is-there-an-easy-way-to-put-my-entire-installation-of-intellij-on-a-usb-stick) it hasn't been updated in a long time, but I'm trying to make it work now.